# Foreach loops correctly - checking with .Any() returns an error

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of `Guid`, where I keep any duplicate `Guid` from my list of items:

```
IEnumerable<Guid> duplicateExists = ListOfMyItems
  .GroupBy(x => x.ID)
  .Where(group => group.Count() > 1)
  .Select(group => group.Key);
```

Now I want to check if duplicate existst, and if so, remove the last occurence of it from `ListOfMyItems`. `DeleteItemFromOrder` just deletes a row from database.

This works:

```
 foreach (var item in duplicateExists)
 {                        
     _ = ListOfMyItems.Remove(ListOfMyItems.Last(x => x.ID == item));
     MyLogic.DeleteItemFromOrder(Bill.ID, item);                      
     return;
 }
```

While this will enter the conditional `if` and then fail on `DeleteItemFromOrder`, telling me that `duplicateExists - sequence contains no elements`:

```
 if(duplicateExists.Any())
 {                        
     _ = ListOfMyItems.Remove(ListOfMyItems.Last(x => x.ID == duplicateExists.First()));
     MyLogic.DeleteItemFromOrder(Bill.ID, duplicateExists.First());                      
     return;
 }
```

Why is the 2nd example failing?

Comment: What's with `_ = `? I mean... I understand it on a technical level, but why?

Comment: Visual adds it automatically for me on file save, profile from company.

Comment: @John I think he is using [`discards`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards)

Comment: @Kunal _"I understand it on a technical level"_.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee I mean discards are useful in some cases (tuples for example) but I don't think they are useful in this particular case. Although VS for some reason suggesting you to assign the unused return value to discard, maybe to show that the method you have called is returning something (not `void`).

Comment: @SᴇM That was basically the reason for my question. It sounds like it's an all-or-nothing thing at OP's company, so I guess that's fair enough. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a result of *Linq* *deferred execution*: when you put

```
 IEnumerable<Guid> duplicateExists = ListOfMyItems
   .GroupBy(x => x.ID)
   .Where(group => group.Count() > 1)
   .Select(group => group.Key);
```

The system actually *doesn't execute* the query; then you have

```
if (duplicateExists.Any())
{                        
    _ = ListOfMyItems.Remove(ListOfMyItems.Last(x => x.ID == duplicateExists.First()));
    MyLogic.DeleteItemFromOrder(Bill.ID, duplicateExists.First());                      
    return;
}
```

And the system does the following:

1. Executes `duplicateExists.Any()` and gets `true`, since duplicates exist
2. Executes `duplicateExists.First()` gets the duplicate and *removes* it from `ListOfMyItems` - `ListOfMyItems.Remove`
3. Tries to execute `duplicateExists.First()` once again for `MyLogic.DeleteItemFromOrder` and now *fails* since `ListOfMyItems` has been *modified* and *has no duplicates* - `duplicateExists` is *empty*

**Quick patch:** *materialize* the `duplicateExists`, *force* the system execute the query and store results in a collection, e.g. array:

```
  IEnumerable<Guid> duplicateExists = ListOfMyItems
   .GroupBy(x => x.ID)
   .Where(group => group.Count() > 1)
   .Select(group => group.Key)
   .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

LINQ uses lazy evaluation. You need to resolve your initial query to a physical list before using it to modify the original data set, like this:

```
var duplicateExists = ListOfMyItems
  .GroupBy(x => x.ID)
  .Where(group => group.Count() > 1)
  .Select(group => group.Key)
  .ToArray();
```